# How to understand synergy in information theory?

Tags: statistics, information-theory

In information theory, **multivariate mutual information (MMI)** could be synergy (negative) or redundancy (positive). To simulate this two cases, assuming three variables X, Y and Z, all of them takes 0 or 1 (binary variable). And we repeat sampling them 12 times.

**Case 1:**

```
X = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
Y = [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ]
Z = [ 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ]
```

In this case, we assume a mechanism among XYZ taht when both Y and Z are 0 or 1, X takes 0 or 1 respectively. When Y = 0, Z = 1, then X takes 0, and Y = 1, Z = 0, then X takes 1.

The **mmi(X,Y,Z) = -0.1699** in this case, indicating a synergy effect among three variable.

**Case 2:**

```
X = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
Y = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ]
Z = [ 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

the machanism in this case is same as above. The difference is there are more samples of XY takes different value and less samples of both XY are 0 or 1.

The **mmi(X,Y,Z) = 0.0333**, indicating a redundancy.

So far, can I say in these two cases, synergy and redundancy show the similar mechanism (or relationship) among three variables? But how do we understand redundancy and particularly synergy in realistic data?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: In my second example, 
    X   = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
    Z1 = [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ]
    Z2 = [ 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ]
MMI among these three variables is negative value and means synergy, But I don't understand why Z1 and Z2 give more information about X together than separately, it's abstract.

Comment: And variables in the third example have the similar relationship with the second example, but the third one MMI is redundancy. As I learned, synergy and redundancy should reflect different relationship among variables. It's conflict with my example?